# Unable to withdraw/transfer funds from contract (using Remix)

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

I wanted to create a contract where wallets can deposit and withdraw funds, to test the re-entrancy attack.

However, on deploying this contract in Remix VM (London), I'm unable to withdraw using the withdrawAll() and withdraw() functions even when my indicated amount is < deposited funds.

The error is:

> transact to Victim.withdraw errored: VM error: revert.
> revert
> The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

Here's the code, please let me know where I did wrong?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Victim {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function deposit(uint256 _amount) public {
        balances[msg.sender] += _amount;
    }
  
    function withdrawAll() public payable {
        uint256 amount = balances[msg.sender];         
        require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "too much!");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        // uint256 new_balance = balances[msg.sender] - amount;
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
  }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "too much!");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    }
  

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you aren't depositing any amount to the contract. `deposit` function just takes in an int and updates the balance. You send ether to the contract, you need to make it payable and deduce the amount from `msg.value`.

```js
function deposit() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

Now if you try to withdraw, it should work properly.

Comment: It works, you are right! Thank you! I see my mistake now :)